# Image upload in PHP with mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image, image-uploading

I am reading a lot about uploading images with PHP. I have come to the conclusion that it's best to have a folder `/images` to keep the files. And have a db table that holds the path to the file and i'd also like to keep track of what it is an image of (in my case houses).

I would have 3 fields in the table:

- id
- unit
- image

Does this sound like the proper way to handle this? I am unable to find any definitive article on how to do this.

Also, when it comes to uploads, are there any recommended articles on how to accomplish this in the manner I want?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is.**

Although mysql lets you store *images* into *records* just as *strings* or *numbers* it is generally preferred to keep separated *"records"* from *"files"*.

I'd suggest to avoid recording the path to the image.

Instead, as the image is associated with a record, give the image a name that links it to the record. Assuming your table have an unique, primary key, auto-increment, integer field named **id** each image will have filename **id.jpg**

After the upload you'll move the image from the php upload directory to the images directory renaming the file.

For information on how manage file uploads with php google for **php upload files**